# MySQL LEFT OUTER JOIN doesn't work

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, outer-join

I have a problem with my mysql output on the workbench. I'm trying to get the company(qualified_name) together with an timestamp(updated). 
Company and the timestamp are in different tables(the headers are further down). Ignore the id's there were only for me to compare

```
SELECT entity_id, c.id, o.id, o.updated, 
   res_companies.qualified_name 
FROM str_entities as o
    JOIN str_entities c 
       ON c.id = o.owner_id 
          AND c.client = "client" 
    LEFT JOIN res_companies 
       ON entity_id = c.id
where o.status = "active" 
    AND o.entity_type_id = 7
```

MySql Workbench gives me that output [image]

Here is the table header for res_companies [image]

And here is the heder from str_entities [image]

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Where is entity_id coming from? It is too ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

try this and tell us what you get

```
Select count(*) from res_companies rc
Where exists (Select * from str_entities se
             Where id = rc.entity_id
                and client = "client"
                and exists (Select * from str_entities
                            Where owner_id = se.id))
```

Are there any records there ?
If the result is zero (0), then the last column (from the left join) is null because there are simply no records in the table that match the criteria you have specified.

Comment: It is 0 but in the res_companies table are 5000 rows.
That's my problem

Comment: but none of them have an `id` = `entity_Id` that exists in the rows from table `str_entities` which meet your criteria... Do you want all the rows from  `res_companies` no matter what `entity_id` they have ?

Comment: In that select I want to have all orders(str_entity.entity_type_id = 7) to their specific company

Comment: orders? I don't see anything in your SQL about orders... do you mean that entity_Type 7 is entity for orders?

Comment: This sounds like *one table to rule them all* schema nightmare..  Good luck

Comment: Yes entity_type_id = 7 are orders